# In Hyperledger, do the membership service, validating peer, and non-validating peer require public OR private IP address to work?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Given the following Hyperledger set-up:

**Company A**

```
- 1 membership service
- 1 VP
- 1 NVP
```

**Company B**

```
- 1 VP
- 1 NVP
```

Note: To simplify the scenario, there are no VPN or port forwarding in the set-up.

Will the membership service and VPs require a public IP address to work?  Can the NVPs use only private IP address provided that they have a network connection to their corresponding VPs?

Answer (score 0):

The address just needs to be resolvable by the source service. That said, for peers (if company A peers and company B peers must validate eachother), ensure the advertised address is resolvable.

To determine the advertised address, visit :7050/network/peers on one of the peers (with rest enabled).  One can change this address via `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=x.x.x.x:7051` and `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=false` ENV variables.

Comment: Thanks @steven-landers.  Just to clarify, since the VPs of company A and company B need to validate each other, I need to specify their public IP via `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=x.x.x.x:7051`.  While for the NVPs (which do not participate in the validation process, can simply use `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true`?